# how to add and remove a class in jquery every 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

for some reason, this isn't adding and removing a new class on elements with the class of post, every 4 seconds. jquery loads correctly, as does this. chrome shows no errors with the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post').addClass('display').delay(4000).removeClass('display');
});
```

Comment: excuse me for saying so, but that approach looks like a major kludge. Are you sure you really want to do something like that?

Comment: We might be able to provide better answers if you tell us why you are doing this.

Comment: try reproducing in a jsfiddle, and show us the link if so

Comment: The jQuery way to do this is with [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwRD3/).

Comment: basically, i just want the images in a class to appear and disappear, while all the other content stays.

see: http://guardianweb.edulence.com/model8/

looks like shit, obviously, but all those images shouldnt be there

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you listed you want this to happen every 4 seconds you can simply use `setInterval()`

```
var $post = $(".post");
setInterval(function(){
    $post.toggleClass("display");
}, 4000);
```

*Note*, the selector is cached in `$post` to minimize the number of times the DOM needs queried on each interval.

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/uJAdQ/)**

Comment: @KeganQuimby there was an invisible character in Mark's post that caused a syntax error, please copypaste it again.

Comment: Doesn't `setInterval` queue up functions to execute when the active tab lost focus? Or does it just throttle the interval? I can never remember.

Comment: Would caching the function definition (i.e. defining it before the setInterval invocation) have a marginal benefit in the code's execution?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to toggle the class-name after four seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.post').toggleClass('display');
},4000);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cajKS/2/).

For toggling *every* four seconds (although [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10094846/82548) already posted a `setInterval` option while I was adding this to my post. ...I'm leaving it, but I acknowledge that Mark got it first):

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('.post').toggleClass('display');
},4000);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cajKS/3/).

References:

- [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: The `delay` param in `setTimeout/setInterval` is a number and I am not sure what happens when you pass it as a string.

Comment: Strings? Strings..? I have no *idea* whatever you might mean..! *Cough* ~edited~ *cough* ...

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why I didn't think of this. But I'll keep my solution as-is in case someone wants to implement functionality other than simple toggling.

Answer (score 3):

`.delay` only works with other animations methods, not `addClass` or `removeClass`. Try this:

```
$('.post').addClass('display');
setTimeout(function(){ $('.post').removeClass('display'); },4000);
```

If you want it to continue adding and removing, you need to get more creative. You could use `setInterval` and an 8000-ms delay, but that would delay the first `addClass` as well. Another approach is to use nested setTimeouts and a recursive function call (along with `toggleClass` to shorten the code):

```
function addRemoveClass() {
    var delay = 4000; // milliseconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.post').toggleClass('display');
        addRemoveClass();
    }, delay);
};
addRemoveClass();
```

​    ​
http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jU8cj/

(Set it to 1000 ms and set `.display` to be transparent, and *voila* -- [you've just re-invented the `blink` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jU8cj/2/).)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  setInterval(addRemoveClass,4000); 
});

function addRemoveClass() {
   $('.post').toggleClass('display');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) on [`queue`d](http://api.jquery.com/queue) actions in jQuery. Fortunately, adding an item to a queue is relatively straightforward:

```
$(selector).delay(duration).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).doStuff();
    doOtherStuff();
    next();
});
```

The parameter provided to the function is a function to tell the queue to continue, in case you want to perform an asynchronous action, such as using `$.ajax`.

To get a loop, simply re-queue the queued function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    function toggleDisplayClass(next) {
        $(this).toggleClass('display')  //toggles the class
            .delay(4000)                //waits 4 seconds
            .queue(toggleDisplayClass); //requeued
        next();                         //continues on the queue
    }
    $('.post').queue(toggleDisplayClass);
});
```

You can see this in action on [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwRD3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  // ready
        var refresh=function(){

        $('.post').toggleClass('display'); //switch

                 }//end refresh
    setInterval(refresh,4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.delay()` only delays animations, not functions. You could use JavaScript's native`setTimeout` method.

```
function toggleDisplay() {
    $('.post').toggleClass("display");
    setTimeout(function(){ toggleDisplay(); },'1000');
}
toggleDisplay();
```