# Add/Remove classes in loop

Tags: jquery

I have 3x span which need to have a class added/removed like this:

```
<span class="w1 selected">Hello</span>
<span class="w2">Bonjour</span>
<span class="w3">Bon Giorno</span>
```

It starts with the class "selected" on the first span, after 2 seconds the class "selected" gets removed from the first span and added to the 2nd span. Then the third and back to the first, in a loop. I am struggling to get this working. I am using `addClass("selected).delay(2000).removeClass("selected")`. However this is not doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

The difference between previous posts is that I have 3 different spans that need to have the class "selected" added and removed in sequence, so 2 seconds on span 1, 2 seconds on span 2, 2 seconds on span3 then back again on span1 etc. I can add the class using setinterval but then it fires for all 3 spans at the same time. Anyone has any suggestion as how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you really have to down mark this question? Thanks a lot! No it is actually different if you check the other post. If you read my question properly you can see the difference. I have multiple spans that need to have the class added/removed in a sequence and I can't get that to work, hence my question. Let me know if you can help or not but this is not useful at all for me.

Comment: Hi Wim, your question is indeed not a duplicate of the question @zzzzBov stated. However, I did find the answer to your question in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517754/jquery-fadein-fadeout-each-element-sequently) and changed it to your needs in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ka2bfqop/.

Comment: I'm also coming from the review queue and I voted to reopen it because it isn't a duplicate of the linked question. What Sanderfish posted is what probably you want, but I'll leave a small fiddle with another attempt https://jsfiddle.net/5a6sp7t8/2/

Comment: Here's my take on it: https://jsfiddle.net/5a6sp7t8/4/

Comment: I thought a bit more about it and I don't like rotating the array, here's an improved (in my opinion) version: https://jsfiddle.net/5a6sp7t8/5/

Comment: Thanks guys. @GeorgSchölly yes this is what I tried to achieve. Thanks Sanderfish, appreciated. Your solution is good, however, I wanted to have all greetings displayed with a highlighted colour in a loop. Georg has the correct solution in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog, another good solution!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a simple repeating queue. The mistake you're making is identical to the mistake being made in ["how to add and remove a class in jquery every 4 seconds"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10094756/497418), which is why I closed it as a duplicate. As others seem to disagree with me, I will go ahead and answer this one to explain the details more clearly.

[`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) do not interact with jQuery's animation queue. You can only use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) with [`queue`d](http://api.jquery.com/queue) functions, such as `queue`, `animate`, `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, etc…

To make `addClass` and `removeClass` work in a queue, you can simply wrap them in a call to `.queue()`:

```
$(...).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    next();
}).delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    next();
});
```

As I said in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10095162/497418):

> The parameter provided to the function is a function to tell the queue to continue, in case you want to perform an asynchronous action, such as using `$.ajax`.

Everything above is the same between questions, it's here where they diverge *slightly*.

Having multiple elements isn't particularly important for being able to queue them in sequence. All that is needed is a single element to hold the queue, and to iterate over the entire collection of elements within the queue.

```
//this function builds the queue chain for each of
//the elements in the selection
function toggleSelected(next) {
  var $this = $(this);

  //select the elements that need to be toggled through
  $('.a, .b, .c').each(function (i, elem) {
    //add a queue chain for each element individually
    $this.queue(function (n) {
      $(elem).addClass('selected');
      //n was used to avoid conflicting with `next` above
      n();
    }).delay(2000).queue(function (n) {
      $(elem).removeClass('selected');
      n();
    });
  });

  //after every element's been queued up, run this
  //function again to loop infinitely
  $this.queue(toggleSelected);

  next();
}

//pick an element, any element
//here I went with .a because it was in the collection
//it could just as easily have been window or document
//or body or html or ...
$('.a').queue(toggleSelected);
```

```js
function toggleSelected(next) {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $('.a, .b, .c').each(function (i, elem) {
    $this.queue(function (n) {
      $(elem).addClass('selected');
      n();
    }).delay(2000).queue(function (n) {
      $(elem).removeClass('selected');
      n();
    });
  });
  
  $this.queue(toggleSelected);
  next();
}

$('.a').queue(toggleSelected);
```

```css
span {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a"></span>
<span class="b"></span>
<span class="c"></span>
```

Comment: Many thanks @zzzzBov this is what I was looking for, but I couldn't understand why delay wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation too, very helpful.

Comment: I did check out your previous answer @zzzzBov and tried it out on my code but it only rotated the whole sequence at once and couldn't figure out how to do this in a loop. Thanks again.